# How to create remote repository, and update it via apt-get?

Tags: linux, apt, remote

I have a remote repository with some files. Let's say, a folder in this address `89.xxx.xxx.xxx:9999/myData` which contains: `data1.txt` and `data2.txt`

In my computer, I want to update the `myData` package using something like:

`sudo apt-get install myData` (or update, instead of install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a repository with proper structure and it should be built and signed with proper tools.
Here are some tutorials that might help you in this, [Ubuntu Repo Questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)